# Get $argv from a string with PHP

Tags: php, argv

We know that can easily get the argument array from the command line with the predefined variable `$argv`.

Is there any easy way to get the array from a string instead of the command line ?
I need to write some tests for related library.

For example, when you run `script.php -a b -c d`, in `script.php`,
you could get `$argv` with value `["script.php", "-a", "b", "-c", "d"]`.
So here my question is that, inside a php script,
how can I get this array from a string, say `"-a b -c d"` here not by passing the string to the command line but to a variable ?

I don't need to parse the options here.

The most simple way to do is:

```
$array = preg_split ("/\s+/", $str);
```

However, this cannot cover the strings with spaces inside the option value.
Say:

```
-a "some thing"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the array from a string"?

Comment: @RobbieAverill For example, when you run `script.php -a b -c d`, in `script.php`, you could get `$argv` with value `["script.php", "-a", "b", "-c", "d"]`. So here my question is that, inside a php script, how can I get this array from a string, say `"-a b -c d"` here?

Comment: At the end of your question you are hinting that there is a different between what is called flags and arguments with values. If you are looking for a generic solution I suggest that you use a 3rd party lib like https://github.com/nategood/commando, witch this you can more or less pass in the string and then access your values with a nice API.

Comment: @Michael That's not what I want, see the answer.

Comment: @PanwenWang I understood your problem. With the lib I suggested you can feed `explode (" ", $yourString)` into the constructor like `new Command(explode(" ", $yourString));` and then you can read your command, flags and their values using that class.

Comment: @Michael `explode(" ", $yourString)` will definitely destruct this: `-a "some thing"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Nobody answered this, I would propose one solution here:

```
function getArgv ($string) {
    global $argv;
    preg_match_all ('/(?<=^|\s)([\'"]?)(.+?)(?<!\\\\)\1(?=$|\s)/', $string, $ms);
    $argv = $ms[2];
}

getArgv("-a b -c d");
print_r ($argv);
getArgv('-a \'b  -c d\' -c "da  fwe\" a" awf="sadf"');
print_r ($argv);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [0] => -a
    [1] => b
    [2] => -c
    [3] => d
)
Array
(
    [0] => -a
    [1] => b  -c d
    [2] => -c
    [3] => da  fwe\" a
    [4] => awf="sadf"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or just let PHP do the job:

```js
$arguments = '-a b -c d --efg="asd lol"';

$serializedArguments = shell_exec(
    sprintf('%s -r "echo serialize(\\$argv);" -- %s', PHP_BINARY, $arguments)
);

var_dump(unserialize($serializedArguments));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Slam's answer (I don't believe in regex for that kind of job), here is what I ended up with:

```
/**
 * Returns the argv array version of the given param string.
 * This function assumes that the php cli is available as "php" on your system.
 * 
 * @param string $str
 * @return array
 */
function paramStringToArgv(string $str): array
{
    // the array shift removes the dash I had as first element of the argv, your mileage may vary
    $serializedArguments = shell_exec(
        sprintf('php -r "array_shift(\\$argv); echo serialize(\\$argv);" -- %s', $str)
    );
    return unserialize($serializedArguments);
}
```

The above code will output something like this

```
array(5) {
    [0] => string(6) "import"
    [1] => string(12) "Ling.Chronos"
    [2] => string(15) "efg=some things"
    [3] => string(10) "--sugar=no"
    [4] => string(2) "-d"
}
```